# Spring AMQP publisher confirms in a amqp outbound gateway

Tags: spring-amqp

I am using spring amqp publishing my messages to RabbitMQ using an outbound gateway. I have set publisher confirms on the connection factory and added my custom callback listener.

The problem is that my CorrelationData is always null and i can't add any correlation data on an outbound gateway. This is only applicable for an outbound channel adapter.

For an outbound gateway will publisher confirms even work?

EDIT
My configuration is below. I looked through the SI code and yes, publisher confirms, are enabled. The problem is what I do when I receive a NACK? 
Because of the outbound gateway I don't need a correlation id to handle the response, there is already a thread listening on a temporary reply queue for the response.

What exactly is the point of using publisher confirms with an outbound gateway? If no response is coming or my Rabbit nodes go down I will encounter exceptions. Is there a scenario when I will lose messages?

```html
<rabbit:connection-factory id="rabbitConnectionFactory"
                               host="someip" port="5672"
                               username="username"
                               password="password"
                               virtual-host="vhost"
                               publisher-confirms="true"/>

    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"/>

    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory"
                     confirm-callback="messagesConfirmCallback"/>
```

```html
 <int-amqp:outbound-gateway
            request-channel="channel"
            amqp-template="amqpTemplate"
            exchange-name="exchange"
            routing-key-expression="headers['queueSpecific']+'.queue'">
        <amqp:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="retryAdvice"/>
        </amqp:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int-amqp:outbound-gateway>
```

And my callback is also simple

```html
@Component
public class MessagesConfirmCallback implements RabbitTemplate.ConfirmCallback {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessagesConfirmCallback.class);

    @Override
    public void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack) {
        if(ack){
            LOGGER.info("ACK received");
        }
        else{
            LOGGER.info("NACK received");
        }
    }
}
```

This

Comment: Yes, they work; please show your configuration.

Comment: Sorry; I mis-read your question; no, we don't currently support them on gateways; I guess we assumed that with a gateway, you don't really need a confirm because you get a reply but, yes, I can see that you might want to get NACKs so you can tell the difference between a timeout for a bad route Vs. the server replying late. Feel free to open an 'Improvement' [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT). In the meantime, I'll see if I can think of a work-around.

Comment: My scenario is this: I have 2 Rabbit nodes and I start publishing. At some point I kill the Rabbit master. From what I read, it is possible that messages might be lost between this transition when the slave will became the new master and publish confirms should give me a nack in this scenario. This way I can retry and I won't lose messages. In my tests though I always receive an AmqpIOException and I added to my retry advice and things will be ok. But is there any chance I can still lose messages?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't see an easy work around with the gateway; the underlying `RabbitTemplate` only supports adding correlation data on `send()` methods, not the `sendAndReceive` methods.

The two options I can think of is to (1) use a pair of outbound and inbound adapters (instead of the gateway), but you'll have to do your own request/reply correlation in that case.

Alternatively (2), use the `RabbitTemplate.execute()` and in the `doInRabbit` callback, add code similar to that in the `RabbitTempalate.doSendAndReceive`, while setting the correlation data as is done in `doSend()`.

I opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3582).

Comment: This is now implemented and available in the Spring Integration 4.2 milestones (release will be later this summer).

Comment: I saw this in spring int reference `RabbitTemplate can be configured with a specific queue for replies; headers are added to the outbound message for request/reply correlation. It is important that the consuming application returns these headers unchanged. The headers are spring_reply_correlation and spring_reply_to. If the consuming application is a Spring Integration application, these headers will be managed automatically, including the case where that application might send a request/reply to a third application using an outbound gateway.` Does it mean we have a workaround?

Comment: No. `...the underlying RabbitTemplate only supports adding correlation data on send() methods, not the sendAndReceive methods....`. Although that is now available in the upcoming Spring AMQP 1.5 release (currently available in milestone1). The aforementioned Spring Integration JIRA depends on that change.